# SSRS: Stop large row moving to new page

Tags: reporting-services

I have a small issue when rendering my report.

I'm pulling a list of objects on an agreement, each object has an undefined character length, some consist of several lines of text, others a single line.

Issue is, each row that contains a large amount of text is moving to a new page in entirety, what I would like to happen is that the row split across on to the next page.

In other words, if a page can only take 5 more lines/rows and a single row hold 15 lines of text, then I want the first 5 lines of the row on the bottom of the current page and then the remaining 10 lines of text moved to the top of the next page.

I've played with all the row grouping settings in SSRS with no luck.

I hope my explanation makes sense.

Thanks in advance,
Dane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than break a row into multiple pages, have you considered transforming your data set by breaking large rows up into multiple smaller rows?

Comment: That makes sense, any suggestions on how I would go about doing this?

Comment: Can you edit the data in the database prior to pulling it into your report?

Comment: Yeah, I can do that, I'd need to drop the data into a temporary table and then I can go wild.

Comment: There is always an option to do more in SQL or more in the Report Designer. I usually opt to do more with the data in SQL, unless it is pure formatting, or unless there is some limitation with the Report Designer. In this case, it seems easier to use SUBSTRING() to break long text field values into multiple records, then pull that data set into your report.